# почему переменная не становится глобальной в функции

Tags: javascript, функции, radio

у меня есть функция

```
function getRadioGroupValue(radioGroupObj) {
  var val = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < radioGroupObj.length; i++)
    if (radioGroupObj[i].checked) {
    val += +radioGroupObj[i].value;
  }
}
```

И из-за этих аргументов я не могу эту переменную с другой сложить.

Comment: Понятно ровно ничего!

Comment: val += radioGroupObj[i].value;

Comment: Если я верно понял вопрос: убери `var`, то есть инициализируй переменную без ее объявления, вот так: `val = 0;`. Еще можно через свойство глобального объекта (`window.val`) работать. Но вообще, глобальные переменные/свойства для решения локальных задач == плохо. Глобальными лучше делать _только_ объекты, которые предполагается использовать в других скриптах (и делать это с большой осторожностью).

Comment: yar85, и ответ igor и ваш в комбинации помогли)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция с названием, начинающимся словом "get", должна что-то возвращать.

```
function getRadioGroupValue(radioGroupObj) {
  ...
  return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому надо, код js:

```
function getRadioGroupValue(radioGroupObj) {
  val = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < radioGroupObj.length; i++)
    if (radioGroupObj[i].checked) {
      val += +radioGroupObj[i].value;
    }

  total = col * val + minPrice;
  rez.innerHTML = total;
  return val;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="calc__select">
                  <span class="calc__select-title">Кладка из пеноблока</span>
                  <select
                    onchange="calcSelect()"
                    id="type_design"
                    class="button calc__select-select"
                  >
                    <option value="0">Не требуется</option>
                    <option value="6400">Требуется</option>
                    <option value="0">Пока незнаю</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: никому не нужен этот код, потому что он вообще не рабочий и не ясно из него ничего.

Comment: Алексей, вы мне вообще не помогли) сами разберитесь в нём, а потом пишите) с удовольствием посмотрю!

Comment: а что тут разбираться? где тут вызов функции getRadioGroupValue? .......а дальше как с ней работать? а  где в представленном коде вообще radio? их нет. так что тут куски кода никак с собой не связанные